# Order confirmation mail content based on the Product type

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento site. My client's requirement is to send Order confirmation email with some content for Gift Card Product type and some other content for simple product type.

Please can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure but maybe this extension is the solution for your needs:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-email-attachments.html

Automatically attach pdf documents to outgoing sales emails.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I need to customize the content of email based on product type

Comment: This could be an approach:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/288526/